# Creating Firefox 4-like menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, firefox4

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this... I know how to do the titlebar button and everything, its just the menu itself I am having troubles with, for example the buttons are split, and they open a menu.

Does anyone know where any samples are?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?  Is it the little triangle control to the right that, when you mouse hover over it, opens a submenu?

Comment: Please post a screen grab, not everyone here uses Firefox.

Comment: No, its a big orange button on the left... I cant get screen grabbing to work.

Comment: Also, I am hoping to do it in Windows Forms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, use the [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) for having full control of the window chrome.

[image]